# How to add several time periods into date cventry in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I am using  `moderncv` package, `banking` style I want to list several time periods in one `\cventry`. 
Best thing I managed is to use more than one `\cventry`, but this leaves too big spacing between entries.

```latex
\cventry{July 2016-- September 2016}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}{}
\cventry{July 2017-- September 2017}{Junior researcher}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{July 2018-- September 2018}{Junior researcher}{}{}{}{}
```

Is there any reasonable way how to solve this?[image]

Comment: Try `\cventry{\begin{tabular{@l@{}} ... \end{tabular}`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that  `{@l@{}}` produces some kind of error, so in the end I used 
 '\begin{tabular}{r@{~--~}l}  .... \end{tabular}, which leads to the output I was hoping for.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. The table preamble is supposed to be  `{@{}l@{}}` (load the `array` package, if you don't already do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get what you want is to use the following both commands:

```
\cventry[0pt]{July 2016-- September 2016}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}{}
\cvitem{}{\emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2017-- September 2017}}
```

With `[0pt]` you force `\cventry` to not add addidional space after the paragraph and with `\cvitem` you can add the missing informations -- use one `\cvitem` for one additional line. Please see that you have the italic formatting in `cvitem` by yourself.

If you have to add more lines use `[0pt]` also for the `\cvitem`s. Only the last `\cvitem` needs no `[0pt]`:

```
\cventry[0pt]{July 2016-- September 2016}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}{} % <===============================================================
\cvitem[0pt]{}{\emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2017-- September 2017}} % <====================
\cvitem{}{\emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2018-- September 2018}} % <====================
```

The third possibility is to use only one `\cventry` and add the additional lines in the last parameter, creating an minipage in font size `\small`:

```
\cventry{July 2015 -- September 2015}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}%
{\normalsize % <========================================================
  \emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2016 -- September 2016}\\
  \emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2016 -- September 2016}
}
```

With `\normalsize` you get the standard font size back.

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\cventry[0pt]{July 2016-- September 2016}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}{} % <===============================================================
\cvitem[0pt]{}{\emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2017-- September 2017}} % <====================
\cvitem{}{\emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2018-- September 2018}} % <====================

\cventry{July 2015 -- September 2015}{Junior researcher}{Slovak academy of sciences}{Bratislava}{}%
{\normalsize % <========================================================
  \emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2016 -- September 2016}\\
  \emph{Junior researcher} \hfill \emph{July 2016 -- September 2016}
} 

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]

or with more additional lines:

[image]

and the third possibility:

[image: third possibility]